# SQL Server calculated column using group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, ssms, calculated-columns

I'm attempting to create a calculated column using 3 columns from a separate table grouped by a foreign key in SSMS. What I have is a linking table called OrderLines that links the Orders and Products tables. The OrderLines table contains a RowID(PK), ItemPrice, Quantity, and OrderID(FK). The Orders table contains the primary key of OrderID and is the table I'd like to add the SubTotal column to. So the formula I need is ((ItemPricexQuantity) grouped by OrderID) but I can't figure out a solution.

[OrderLines Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvddN.png)

[OrdersTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MURHK.png)

I've figured out how to get it as a column using a query and can create it using a view but was wondering if it can be added to the Orders table as a calculated column.

The query is that creates the column I need is:

```
Select orderid, SUM(itemprice*Quantity)
from orderitems
group by orderID
```

Thank you for your time,
Stephen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, we need to be able to copy and paste your table schemas and data from your question. That's impossible with pictures. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and, regarding posting pictures, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussion earlier: [How do I Specify Computed Columns in a Table which are based on another Column in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740253/how-do-i-specify-computed-columns-in-a-table-which-are-based-on-another-column-i)

> ```
> create table orderitems 
> (
> orderId int,
> itemid int,
> productId int,
> itemprice decimal(18,2),
> quantity int
> )
> GO
> ```

> ```
> create table orders
> (
> orderId int,
> shipAmount decimal(18,2),
> TaxAmount decimal(18,2)
> )
> GO
> ```

> ```
> insert into orderitems (orderId,itemid,productId,itemprice,quantity) values
> (1,1,2,1199,1),
> (2,2,8,489.99,1),
> (3,3,1,2517,1),
> (3,4,9,415,1),
> (4,5,2,1199,1),
> (5,6,10,299,1),
> (6,7,10,299,1)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> insert into orders (orderId,shipAmount,TaxAmount) values
> (1,5,58.71),
> (2,5,58.72),
> (3,10,58.73),
> (4,10,58.74),
> (5,5,58.75),
> (6,5,58.76);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select * from orders
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> orderId | shipAmount | TaxAmount
> ------: | :--------- | :--------
>       1 | 5.00       | 58.71    
>       2 | 5.00       | 58.72    
>       3 | 10.00      | 58.73    
>       4 | 10.00      | 58.74    
>       5 | 5.00       | 58.75    
>       6 | 5.00       | 58.76
> ```

> ```
> create function udfMyTable (@orderID  as int)
> returns decimal(18, 2)
> as
> begin
>   declare @res as decimal(19, 2);
>
>   Select
>     @res = SUM(itemprice*Quantity)
>   from orderitems
>   where
>     orderID = @orderID    
>
> return @res;
> end
> GO
> ```

> ```
> alter table orderitems add SubTotal as dbo.udfMyTable(orderID)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> alter table orders add SubTotal as dbo.udfMyTable(orderID)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> Select * from orderitems
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> orderId | itemid | productId | itemprice | quantity | SubTotal
> ------: | -----: | --------: | :-------- | -------: | :-------
>       1 |      1 |         2 | 1199.00   |        1 | 1199.00 
>       2 |      2 |         8 | 489.99    |        1 | 489.99  
>       3 |      3 |         1 | 2517.00   |        1 | 2932.00 
>       3 |      4 |         9 | 415.00    |        1 | 2932.00 
>       4 |      5 |         2 | 1199.00   |        1 | 1199.00 
>       5 |      6 |        10 | 299.00    |        1 | 299.00  
>       6 |      7 |        10 | 299.00    |        1 | 299.00
> ```

> ```
> select * from orders
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> orderId | shipAmount | TaxAmount | SubTotal
> ------: | :--------- | :-------- | :-------
>       1 | 5.00       | 58.71     | 1199.00 
>       2 | 5.00       | 58.72     | 489.99  
>       3 | 10.00      | 58.73     | 2932.00 
>       4 | 10.00      | 58.74     | 1199.00 
>       5 | 5.00       | 58.75     | 299.00  
>       6 | 5.00       | 58.76     | 299.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c58f4c7f0d750cb580f4db0d592100f0)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The code you created didn't group by OrderID, as you can see by OrderID 3. From your code I was able to create a second function to group by and get the proper SubTotal column on the orders table.

`create function udfMyTable2 (@orderID  as int)

returns decimal(18, 2)

as

begin

  declare @res as decimal(19, 2);

  
  Select

    @res = SUM(subtotal)

  from orderitems

  where

    orderID = @orderID   

 group by OrderID 


return @res;

end`

Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need something below

```
select  O.orderID ,sum（itemprice*Quantity）Orders O inner join OrderLines ol 
on O.OrderID=ol.OrderId
group by  O.OrderID
```